# how to set a Drop down filled to it's value and text on edit mode in AngularJS and asp.net webApi

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to set the drop down to it's value and text on edit view
but all the other text filled are set except the drop down

this is the html part

```
 //Html  content
   <select class="form-control" id="pcategory" ng-model="pcategory" ng-options="c.CID as c.Name for c in pcategoryA">
        <option value="">-- Select Category --</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" ng-model="price" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" ng-model="quantity" />

    // angularJS
     $http.get('/api/product/' + $routeParams.id).success(function (data)
    {

        $scope.pcategory = data.CID, // I cannot set the drop down
        $scope.name = data.name,
        $scope.price = data.price,
        $scope.quantity = data.quantity

    });
```

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value you're trying to set is not a possible value in the list "pcategoryA" then it will not work.  Does data.CID always match an id in the pcategoryA list?

Comment: The value is in the "pcategoryA"  
Yes it alway match a value
data.CID

Comment: I was able to solve it with this trick
$scope.pcategory = ""+data.CID+""
but I don't know how the magic happen.